# Expected Expression Error in my Python script

Tags: python

I'm on Visual Studio trying to update my Itch Quiz Game and when I tried to test an Else function that follows with a print function it said I had an Expected Expression error. I tried to fix it but it didn't work. Please help

Heres my code

```
import time


print("Math Game")
print("")

score = 0
    #intro 
print("Welcome to 5 Questions")
answer6 = input("Type Begin to Begin")
if answer6 == "Begin":
    
    score +=0

#Question 1
print("Whats 2 + 2")
answer1 = input("Enter answer")

if answer1 == "4":
    else: ---THIS IS THE ERROR
    print("Test")
    
    
    score += 1

    #Question 2
print("Whats 4 * 2")
answer2 = input("Enter answer")

if answer2 == "8":
    score += 1

        #Question 3
print("Whats the root square of 16")
answer3 = input("Enter answer")

if answer3 == "4":
    score += 1

            #Question 4
print("Who made the laws of gravity")
answer4 = input("Enter answer")

if answer4 == "Issac Newton":
    score += 1

               #Question 5
print("Whats Apples frist device the Phone or the Computer")
answer4 = input("Enter answer")

if answer4 == "Computer":
    score += 1

    print("you got " + str(score) + "/5")
    time.sleep(5)
print("Good Bye!")
```

Comment: You're missing the body of the `if` statement. And `else:` needs to be at the same indentation level as the matching `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that the body of the `if-else` statement in `Question 1` is empty. You need to have at least one line of code inside every `if/else statement`. If nothing should be done, you can use the keyword `pass`:

```
if answer1 == "4":
    # ...
    score += 1 # this should go here, when answer1=='4', right?
    # ...
else: 
    pass
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_pass.asp

---

Also, all clauses of the `if-else` statement should have the same indentation level.